# Using getTrustedHtml method to get html from a url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve html code from a URL to use as my templateUrl and using getTrustedHtml to do it, however, I'm receiving a $sce:unsafe error.

```
    app.directive('showResult', ['$sce', function($sce){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: $sce.getTrustedHtml('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aidanhall21/aidanhall21.github.io/master/showResult.html')

};
    }]);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The `angular` tag is for angular 2+. I've changed your `angular` tag to `angularjs` so you get the correct help

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: try: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl, I'm not 100%, but worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/U3pVM/57716/

2 things:

you need to use `trustAsResourceUrl`, because you want to access a remote URL: [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl).

directive will be like this:

```
.directive('showResult', ['$sce', function($sce){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aidanhall21/aidanhall21.github.io/master/showResult.html')

};
```

You have to do the binding correctly if you want the string to be displayed.Where the directive will be used, you have to do

```
 .controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.coucou = {name:"A NAME HERE"};
    })
```

and in your html:

```
<show-result info="coucou"></show-result>
```

enjoy!